# Which version of openMP is supported by icpc 13.01?

Tags: c++, openmp, icc

I'm using the icpc, version 13.01 for compiling my c++ code. Since I want to use openMP for parallelization, I want to know which version of it is supported by the compiler. I found some methods to find it out for g++ compiler, but not for ipcp... Can anyone offer a hint?

Comment: You can determine this via _OPENMP as demonstrated here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/477727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's iteresting for someone else: After spending more time on research I found out, that it should support openmp version 3.1:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-and-fortran-compilers-now-support-the-openmp-31-specification/

The comment of Jeff also is very helpful!